# Subject of Observer design pattern an interface or a super class?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, uml

I'm studying design patterns from a course at coursera. They have there course notes in which they define the `Subject` of the observer design pattern as super class as shown in the image and code below

**UML**
[image]

**CODE (SUBJECT)**
[image]

Now I think the `Subject` class  is useless by itself until a subclass inherit from it and make any specific subject. In that case shouldn't the `Subject` be a java `interface` instead ? What is the reason that the `Subject` is not a java interface but the `Observer` is.

Is there any specific reason for that. I'm a little confused about this.

Thanks

Comment: *I think the Subject class is useless by itself until a subclass inherit from it and make any specific subject*- Why is that?

Comment: @user7 because what else is it doing other than attaching and detaching observers and keeping a list of them which is eventually going to be present in sub classes when we will inherit from the subject in other words now the sub classes have the same same code after inheriting plus there own additional code so wouldn't it be same if subject was an interface and classes implement that functionality ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observer D P is a simple.

1. The Subject is the entity that the Observer watches.
2. The Subject is single entity and the Observers can be more than one.
3. The Subject has the List observers, but the Observer will have the Subject.
4. Any change in the Subject will be notified to all the observers that the Subject stores in the form of a list.
5. We can have the Subject as interface too. All depends on way we implement the above points.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I guess you are right. Implementation can vary as long as all the points holds true.

Answer (score 6):

If `Subject` was an interface, then every class that implements `Subject` must re-implement all the `registerObserver`, `unregisterObserver`, and `notify` methods which are very standard.

You may say that you will put those methods into a helper class so that every derived `Subject` can just delegate the tasks to this helper. But after all, you have to duplicate the delegation code for all derived `Subject` classes. Althought the delegation code is short and straight-forward, that duplication is still frustrating.

You can find that argument near the end of this very interesting article of Uncle Bob: http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2015/01/08/InterfaceConsideredHarmful.html

Comment: Thanks that was a nice and funny read answered a lot of other frustrating questions

Comment: What is his point exactly by interface considered harmful? Does he mean it that interface is not good?

Comment: Because interface is a workaround to partially solve or mitigate the problem of “not supporting multi-inheritance”. Interface is not bad, but because of its invention, the language designers didn’t solve the problem in a more correct way, so that we don’t need interface, just abstract classes are fine, like C++.